# Excel SUMIF with Date&Time Cells Compared to Array of Date&Time Cells (OR Statement)

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have found numerous examples online to use SUMIF and SUMIFS statements in Excel when comparing dates contained in a data set to fixed dates written in the formula; however, I am unable to locate information related to comparing dates contained in a data set to an array of other dates contained in a data set.

**Example scenario**:

Suppose I send technicians to complete services at multiple times throughout the day, and many of these service calls overlap. At the time that a new service call is received, I already have multiple technicians out at other calls. I'd like to account for the number of technicians unavailable at the time a service call is received due to already being engaged in another call.

Here is an example data set format (direct image embedding not available for me yet:

#### Screenshot of Example Data File in Excel

[image: Screenshot of Example Data File in Excel]):

Column A = Unique Order Numbers

Column B = Date and Time Service Requested

Column C = Date and Time Service Completed

Column D = Number of Technicians Responding

Column E = (calculated) Number of Technicians Unavailable

**Focused question**:

How do I sum the values in Column D, for which the date and time appearing in cell B2 is < any of the dates and times appearing in array C3:C9? (This is an OR problem). And then the calculations will need to be continued with each subsequent date and time appearing in Column B (e.g., sum the values in Column D, for which the date and time appearing in cell B3 is < any of the dates and times appearing in array C4:C9).

Assume I have sorted my data by the date and time appearing in Column B, most recent first.

In the example I have provided, order number 000008 was received on 09/30/2010 at 11:47:14 PM, but 9 technicians were still out engaged in other calls that were not completed by the time this new service call was received (yellow highlighted entries). How do I get Excel to calculate the value 9 (cell E2 that I have currently manually summed)?

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Instead of SUMIF, consider using Excel function DGET (and other d-functions). They have more power and flexibility.

Comment: I get that the number of unavailable technicians is 8, not 9?

Comment: Thank you so much @NetMage--the formula worked perfectly! My screenshot of the example file didn't display times with the dates in the cells--that made it impossible to know that the manual count was 9 (the highlighted yellow cells indicated which completed dates/times were > the received date/time of order #000008).

Comment: Thank you so much @ClintB--your formula also worked perfectly! This was my first time reaching out to the community for assistance, and I'm so glad that I did.

Answer (score 0):

In cell E2, try this:

```
=SUMIF(C2:$C$9, ">"&B2, D2:$D$9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you order by the order number (which is numeric and will be in order of request time) this formula should do the trick:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,">" & B2,A:A,"<" & A2)
```

This works by:

```
= SUMIFS( D:D, /*Sum the Number of techs currently repsonding*/
          C:C, ">" & B2,  /* WHERE the completion date/time is less than the Request time for the current order */
          A:A,"<" & A2)   /* AND the order number is less than the current order number --Could alternatively use column B:B as the range and B2 as the critera */
```

Edit:
Also need to count the datetime of the above records if the completion date is null.

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,">" & B2,A:A,"<" & A2) + SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,"",A:A,"<" & A2)
```